# Can't bind string containing @ char with mysqli_stmt_bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a problem with my database class. I have a method that takes one prepared statement and any number of parameters, binds them to the statement, executes the statement and formats the result into a multidimentional array.
Everthing works fine until I try to include an email adress in one of the parameters. The email contains an @ character and that one seems to break everything.
When I supply with parameters:

```
$types = "ss" and $parameters = array("email@domain.com", "testtest")
```

I get the error:

> Warning: Parameter 3 to
> mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expected to
> be a reference, value given in
> ...db/Database.class.php on line 63

Here is the method:

```
private function bindAndExecutePreparedStatement(&$statement, $parameters, $types) {
    if(!empty($parameters)) {
        call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge(array($statement, $types), &$parameters));
        /*foreach($parameters as $key => $value) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 's', $value);
        }*/
    }

    $result = array();

    $statement->execute() or debugLog("Database error: ".$statement->error);

    $rows = array();

    if($this->stmt_bind_assoc($statement, $row)) {
        while($statement->fetch()) {
            $copied_row = array();
            foreach($row as $key => $value) {
                if($value !== null && mb_substr($value, 0, 1, "UTF-8") == NESTED) { // If value has a nested result inside
                    $value = mb_substr($value, 1, mb_strlen($value, "UTF-8") - 1, "UTF-8");
                    $value = $this->parse_nested_result_value($value);
                }
                $copied_row[$ke<y] = $value;
            }
            $rows[] = $copied_row;
        }
    }

    // Generate result
    $result['rows'] = $rows;
    $result['insert_id'] = $statement->insert_id;
    $result['affected_rows'] = $statement->affected_rows;
    $result['error'] = $statement->error;

    return $result;
}
```

I have gotten one suggestion that:

> the array_merge is casting parameter
> to string in the merge change it to
> &$parameters so it remains a reference

So I tried that (3rd line of the method), but it did not do any difference.

How should I do? Is there a better way to do this without call_user_func_array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the parameter-binding code in Zend Framework's MySQLi adapter.  I find the parameter-binding API for MySQLi to be hard to use.  It's not the array that needs to be a reference, it's *each element* of the array.

You can see the code I wrote in the `_execute()` method in this class:
http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php

I recommend that you check out PDO.  It's far more easy to use.  You can bind parameters, but it's even easier to just pass the array of parameter values as an array to the PDOStatement's [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) method.